Incrementing pointers in bytes for indexing strided array
I wrote a library whose interface references coordinate data from client side. Clients are expected to provide an array of points that each contains 3 contiguous floats. I have decided to use a strided array representation so the clients can keeping using their own data types.
Suppose the client uses the following Point struct internally (it is NOT visible to the library):
struct Point {
    float xyz[3];
    CustomData data;
    // more data
};

The client shall store some Points in a contiguous storage, and passes relevant info to my library:
struct Interface {
    const float* first_x;  // Pointer to xyz[0] in first Point
    std::ptrdiff_t stride; // Set to sizeof(Point)
    std::ptrdiff_t len;    // Number of contiguous Point
};

Can I access coordinates of each point safely, in standard C++? It appears to me that some form of pointer arithmetic on bytes is unavoidable.
For now, I read the coordinates like this:
void Interface::process_points()
{
    for (std::ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        const float* const pf = reinterpret_cast<const float*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(first_x) + i * stride);
        float x = pf[0];
        float y = pf[1];
        float z = pf[2];
        // do things with x, y, z
    }
}

The stride is skipped by incrementing an aliased char pointer. For now it seems to work correctly, however I don't know if this mixture of pointer arithmetic and char aliasing is well defined behavior in C++.

Can you impose some requirement on the user code like inherting from an interface that you define in the library ?

@wohlstad Perhaps I should named it Config or InputData instead of Interface, since in this example it's only for grouping the pointer and offsets. The points will be accessed very frequently by the library, so requiring the user to implement a virtual function for accessing individual points may not be the best option here.

Not in standard C++, one you have a pointer to the 1st element of float[3] xyz;, you can dereference to get any of the 3 elements, or increment the pointer to 1 past the end - but not dereference that pointer. See Pointer arithmetic.  I think the above pointer calculation falls into "...Other j values result in undefined behavior...."

I don't see a C++ way to access point[1].xyz[0] from point[0].xyz[0] which is not pedantically UB.

@RichardCritten @Jarod42 I'm aware of the usual rules of pointer arithmetic, however I'm not clear about how it plays with char pointer casting. We can examine all bytes of an object by incrementing a casted char pointer (although technically there is no array of chars), so how is it not UB?

Perdantic Standard C++: It's legal when using char pointer to examine the bytes, and a std::memcpy into a float is also legal.  What is not legal is casting the calculated char pointer back to a float pointer and dereferencing the float pointer to access the value of the float.  However in practice just increment the original float pointer to get to the next array no need to go via a char pointer as it does not help sanitize the behaviour.

@RichardCritten Using a char* to examine the bytes of an object seems to be UB before p1839.

Why can't you just:
`  const float* const end = &first_x[len * stride - 1];
while (end >= first_x) {
float x = first_x[0];
float y = first_x[1];
float z = first_x[2];
/* ... do stuff ... */
first_x += stride;
}
`
demo: https://godbolt.org/z/j8o9o5GWW

In general sizeof(Point) will always be a multiple or sizeof(float), changing your stride to be a number of floats rather than number of bytes would remove any uncertainty and shouldn't cause calling applications any issues unless they're using packed structures

I'm wondering if, by using an implicitly created array of float on the storage of the struct     Points, you couldn't access the floats without UB (as far as you don't evaluate the parts that are not floats). first_x = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<float *>(point[0].xyz))? It might be required that the storage be allocated as raw bytes and then the Point be constructed inplace. (I think that implicit creation happens only for arrays of bytes, not arrays of objects)

@Oersted The same storage cannot be both an array of Points and an array of floats. Implicit object creation is not omnipotent, if you access it as a float array here, you can't access it later as an array of Points without othet actions in between. Moreover, std::launder has to conform to the accessibility rule so it's also not of much use here.

@WeijunZhou Thx, you can not overlap different objects in the same location, as in an union or a variant, as long as you're keeping consistent when dereferencing? (I'm probably making wrong assumptions about unions and variant (in the latter, I would have explicitly destroyed a previous object before creating a new one, leaving only the storage intact; on the other hand, I don't know how unions are modeled).

@Oersted No.You can't have two objects that are both within their lifetimes that occupy overlapping memory, provided that neither is a subobject of the other. The implicit object creation just defers the determination of the type, but it still needs to be a single type that gives the program defined behavior. Your suggestion would require both a float array and a Point array to be within their lifetime. Although the accesses are made at different times, as long as nothing happens in between that starts or ends the lifetime (where implicit object creation cannot help), it's illegal.

In unions, the standard explicitly states that the inactive member can become active and be implicitly constructed under some conditions when doing assignment.

@WeijunZhou. Clear. It rules out my idea. Thx

Assuming you control the library API, you could have the user of the library provide a callback function that increments to the next set of float[3].  That will relieve the library the burden of doing the stride and UB casting.  (Even if the UB casting appears to work, it's .)

It is possible to do this in a well defined manner only if your library can get the size of the struct Point at compile time. It can be done as follows:
#include <bit>

static constexpr auto POINT_SIZE = ...;
using point_sized_float_array_t = std::array<float, POINT_SIZE / sizeof(float)>;
using point_sized_byte_array_t = std::array<std::byte, POINT_SIZE / sizeof(std::byte)>;

void process_points(const float* points, std::size_t point_count)
{
    const auto points_bytes_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(points);

    for (std::ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < point_count; ++i)
    {
        const auto point_bytes_ptr = points_bytes_ptr + i * POINT_SIZE;
        point_sized_byte_array_t point_bytes{};

        std::copy_n(points_bytes_ptr, point_bytes.size(), point_bytes.begin());

        const auto point_as_floats = std::bit_cast<point_sized_float_array_t>(point_bytes);

        const float x = point_as_floats[0];
        const float y = point_as_floats[1];
        const float z = point_as_floats[2];
    }
}

Key Points

The only reinterpret_cast used is reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(), which can later be safely accessed. This is unique to byte-like types (char, unsigned char, std::byte), as reading the value from the result of a reinterpret_cast to (almost) any other type leads to undefined behavior.

An std::bit_cast is used to convert a byte array to a float array. This is safe and well-defined as long as the source and destination types have the same size and are trivially copyable. The result of the cast can be safely read from because it creates a copy of the value, not a reference, and therefore avoids clashes with the strict aliasing rule.

As such, the values which remain in x, y, and z may be read from and the program will not lead to undefined behavior. However, it is important to keep in mind that the correctness of those values is probably not actually guaranteed. This is all to say, if you are running some exotic compiler or operating system you might get garbage values.



As commented in the question, P1839 seems to indicate that the pointer arithmetic here is UB. Although that maybe overly pedantic.
